# Open a specific accordion with an anchor link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

EDIT:  This has been solved here:  [Open a specific accordion panel with an external anchor link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447803/open-a-specific-accordion-panel-with-an-external-anchor-link/50448207)

I am looping over the accordion (with Coldfusion) and it is showing the data and working fine.  I am trying to get any of the panels to open based on a link (page.cfm#collapse20).

Here is the accordion code without any Coldfusion...

```js
(function() {
    var searchTerm, panelContainerId;
    // Create a new contains that is case insensitive
    $.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function(n, i, m) {
        return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    $('#accordion_search_bar').on('change keyup paste click', function() {
        searchTerm = $(this).val();
        $('#accordion > .panel').each(function() {
            panelContainerId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            $(panelContainerId + ':not(:containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + '))').hide();
            $(panelContainerId + ':containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + ')').show();
        });
    });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" 
    id="page_container">
    <div id="accordion_search_bar_container">
        <input type="search" 
            id="accordion_search_bar" 
            placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group" 
        id="accordion" 
        role="tablist" 
        aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-success" 
            id="collapseOne_container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseOne" 
                        aria-expanded="true" 
                        aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    One
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Pellentesque convallis dolor</p>
                    <p>Enim at tincidunt magna dapibus vitae</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary" 
            id="collapseTwo_Container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" 
                        role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseTwo" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Two
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Vestibulum in laoreet nisi</p>
                    <p>Sit amet placerat massa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-danger" 
            id="collapseThree_Container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" 
                        role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseThree" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Three
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Curabitur sem eros tempor sit</p>
                    <p>Amet nunc eget, gravida mollis</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, I am just looking for a solution for opening any one of the accordions using an anchored link.

Please let me know if I need to provide more info and thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi Archer, thanks for responding.  So, I put that at the bottom of my page after the other JS, in a script tag, but it's not working for me yet.
Is that the correct way to implement it?

Comment: That should do the trick, yes, but if the accordion hasn't been implemented when it hits that code then it won't work.  That's most likely the issue you're facing.

Comment: Try loading the page and then run that code in the console - that will tell you whether or not it can work.

Comment: I have it right before the closing body tag.  The accordion works but my anchor link isn't taking me there or opening anything.  I am using the right id (collapse) or should it be 'header' or other?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Nothing showing in the console (Chrome) aside from some missing fonts.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: No - run that line of code in the console and see if it opens the page that link points to

Comment: I opened console, went to Sources, added a snippet with the JS code you sent.  Hitting 'run snippet' didn't have any visible effect.  I am super new at Console (and JS!) so thank you for your patience.  StackOverflow is saying I should do 'chat' - let me know if that's better?

Comment: Actually, forget about that - I didn't realise that the code has coldfusion variables in it.  Does the accordion all work okay, and you just want to open a specific page when it loads?

Comment: Correct, the accordion works as intended.  i just want to be able to click an anchor link and have it take you to that panel and open it.

Comment: Okay, in that case you'd be better off changing the question so there's a working accordion (not one full of CF vars) - just plain HTML and JS.  If you use a snippet (the `<>` button in the editor) then you can add them and make a working version.

Comment: Ok, done.  This includes the index.js which is for the search functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that should help.  I've added 3 links at the top, one for each page.  Each link has a data attribute that matches the href attribute of one of the page links in the accordion.  When one is clicked the script will collapse all the pages and then run `.collapse("show")` to show the associated page.

```js
$(function() {

// close all pages for this example
$(".collapse").collapse("hide");

// check the url hash when we first load the page
if (window.location.hash != "") {
    $(window.location.hash).collapse("show");
}

// attach click event handlers to the links with the class page-link
$("a.page-link").on("click", function() {
    var ref = $(this).data("page");
    
    // close all pages
    $(".collapse").collapse("hide");

    // show the selected page
    $(ref).collapse("show");
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="page-link" data-page="#collapseOne">Page 1</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="page-link" data-page="#collapseTwo">Page 2</a>&nbsp;
<a href="#" class="page-link" data-page="#collapseThree">Page 3</a>&nbsp;

<div class="container" 
    id="page_container">
    <div class="panel-group" 
        id="accordion" 
        role="tablist" 
        aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-success" 
            id="collapseOne_container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseOne" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    One
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Pellentesque convallis dolor</p>
                    <p>Enim at tincidunt magna dapibus vitae</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary" 
            id="collapseTwo_Container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" 
                        role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseTwo" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Two
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Vestibulum in laoreet nisi</p>
                    <p>Sit amet placerat massa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-danger" 
            id="collapseThree_Container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" 
                        role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseThree" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Three
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Curabitur sem eros tempor sit</p>
                    <p>Amet nunc eget, gravida mollis</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Archer - that is working for me locally in the same way as it is here.  But I'm not sure how to open one of these panels with a link the way I need it formed (example:  page.cfm#accordion3).

Comment: You could add the links with another loop, similar to the one that adds the pages, and set the `data-page` value the same way you set the `href` value of each page button.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something - I currently have this (static):   <a href="#" class="page-link" data-page="#collapseOne">Page 1</a> Which works when clicked, but going to index.html#collapseOne does not do anything.

Comment: It's not actually changing the page when you click the link - it's executing the Javascript that opens the accordion page.  So changing the page url and adding the hash value won't do anything.

Comment: So does that mean this technique won't accept a URL (from this or another page) and open the desired panel?  Thanks a lot for the help; this has been driving me crazy!

Comment: I'll add a bit of code that checks that when the page opens.

Comment: Hi Archer, I tried the code above but going to: page.html#collapseTwo does not do anything for me.  I changed the JS and the HTML to what you have above.

Comment: Every time I give an answer to a question you then add a "but what about...".  You need to clearly define exactly what you are trying to do, and show us what you've done to try and make it work so we can help fix that specific issue.  You should delete this question now as it's just become a jumbled mess and will be of no value to anyone else in the future.  Make a new question when you can explain clearly exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Archer, sorry this has gone on so long, but in my defense, i stated in my very first post that i needed an anchored link (page.cfm#collapse20) to open a panel.  The link structure you posted does not seem to fully consider that original request.  Believe me, i really appreciate your efforts to help.  But I'm not sure how i could have made my point any more clear. As for posting what i've done, nothing worked, and i thought it'd be best to post the 'working code' in hopes of a solution that works and not trying to force what didn't work.  Again, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I wasn't berating you.  I just think you'd get more specific help if we knew more specific information.  I'm glad I could help somewhat, but you'll get more help if you understand an XY problem and realise that's what this question is.  Good luck :)

Comment: Hi Archer, I will give that a shot and try to explain it better.  Thanks again.