# Open a specific accordion panel with an external anchor link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap accordion setup and working fine.

I need to have links on external pages which will:

A) Take you to the specified panel within the accordion

B) Open the specified panel

The link structure needs to be in this format (example):

**Page.html#collapseTwo**
(the 'collapseTwo' will change, of course, depending on the panel)

The HTML:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" 
    id="page_container">
    <div id="accordion_search_bar_container">
        <input type="search" 
            id="accordion_search_bar" 
            placeholder="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group" 
        id="accordion" 
        role="tablist" 
        aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-success" 
            id="collapseOne_container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseOne" 
                        aria-expanded="true" 
                        aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    One
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Pellentesque convallis dolor</p>
                    <p>Enim at tincidunt magna dapibus vitae</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-primary" 
            id="collapseTwo_Container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingTwo">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" 
                        role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseTwo" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Two
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Vestibulum in laoreet nisi</p>
                    <p>Sit amet placerat massa</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-danger" 
            id="collapseThree_Container">
            <div class="panel-heading" 
                role="tab" 
                id="headingThree">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a class="collapsed" 
                        role="button" 
                        data-toggle="collapse" 
                        data-parent="#accordion" 
                        href="#collapseThree" 
                        aria-expanded="false" 
                        aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Three
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" 
                class="panel-collapse collapse in" 
                role="tabpanel" 
                aria-labelledby="headingThree">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Curabitur sem eros tempor sit</p>
                    <p>Amet nunc eget, gravida mollis</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The JS:

```
  (function() {
    var searchTerm, panelContainerId;
    // Create a new contains that is case insensitive
    $.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function(n, i, m) {
        return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    $('#accordion_search_bar').on('change keyup paste click', function() {
        searchTerm = $(this).val();
        $('#accordion > .panel').each(function() {
            panelContainerId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            $(panelContainerId + ':not(:containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + '))').hide();
            $(panelContainerId + ':containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + ')').show();
        });
    });
}());
```

Comment: have tried using query params instead and implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `url parameters` and do it.

Sample links:
https://output.jsbin.com/talojodupa/1?panel=collapseOne
https://output.jsbin.com/talojodupa/1?panel=collapseTwo

jsbin link: https://jsbin.com/talojodupa/1/edit?html,js,output

```js
(function() {
    var searchTerm, panelContainerId;
    // Create a new contains that is case insensitive
    $.expr[':'].containsCaseInsensitive = function(n, i, m) {
        return jQuery(n).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };

    $('#accordion_search_bar').on('change keyup paste click', function() {
        searchTerm = $(this).val();
        $('#accordion > .panel').each(function() {
            panelContainerId = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
            $(panelContainerId + ':not(:containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + '))').hide();
            $(panelContainerId + ':containsCaseInsensitive(' + searchTerm + ')').show();
        });
    });
  
  /* Function to get url parameter based on param name */
  function getUrlParameter(key) {
    key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
      return "";
    else
      return unescape(results[1]).replace(/<script.*>.*<\/script>/g, "");
  }
  
  var panelId = getUrlParameter('panel');
  if(panelId){
    var $panel = $('#'+panelId);
    $panel.addClass('in');

    $('html,body').animate({
       scrollTop: $panel.offset().top},
    'slow');
  }
  
}());
```

Comment: Hello Shivaji and thanks a lot - that worked perfectly for opening the panels!!  

The only thing left of my request is "A) Take you to the specified panel within the accordion".  

If you add a bunch of panels (or simply a bunch of <br/> between the panels) so that it goes way down the page below the fold, this code does not take you down to the panel.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you so much, Shivaji.  This has been troubling me for many days!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
JS code: 

      $(function () {
            // check if there is a hash in the url
            if (window.location.hash != '') {
                // show the panel based on the hash now.
                $(window.location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
            }

        });
```