# Javascript accordion with anchors for joomla

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, joomla

I do not know javascript and scss very well so I am struggling with creating an accordion for a page.
I would like two options:

1. When one panel is opened, the other collapses.
2. Every heading of a panel has an anchor, and when i go to the link [www.example.com#heading1](http://www.example.com#heading1), the page scrolls to the heading1 and opens its section.

It used to work in this [extension](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/mooaccordion/), but the anchors disappeared suddenly (i've checked in Chrome and Ff).

For now i found in internet this accordion:

```
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="ac">
    <h2 class="ac-q" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
    <div class="ac-a">
      <p>Nulla et sodales nisl. Nam auctor quis odio eu congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ac">
    <h2 class="ac-q" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
    <div class="ac-a">
      <p>Nulla et sodales nisl. Nam auctor quis odio eu congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ac">
    <h2 class="ac-q" tabindex="0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
    <div class="ac-a">
      <p>Nulla et sodales nisl. Nam auctor quis odio eu congue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>  

<script>
"use strict";
! function (i)
{
  function u(o, l)
  {
    var c = this,
      t = {
        init: function ()
        {
          if (Array.isArray(o)) return o.length && o.map(function (e)
          {
            return new u(e, l)
          }), !1;
          this.options = h(
          {
            duration: 600,
            itemNumber: 0,
            aria: !0,
            closeOthers: !0,
            showItem: !1,
            elementClass: "ac",
            questionClass: "ac-q",
            answerClass: "ac-a",
            targetClass: "ac-target",
            onToggle: function () {}
          }, l), this.container = document.querySelector(o), this.elements = this.container.querySelectorAll("." + this.options.elementClass);
          var e = this.options,
            t = e.aria,
            n = e.showItem,
            i = e.itemNumber;
          t && this.container.setAttribute("role", "tablist");
          for (var s = 0; s < this.elements.length; s++)
          {
            var r = this.elements[s];
            r.classList.add("js-enabled"), this.hideElement(r), this.setTransition(r), this.generateID(r), t && this.setARIA(r)
          }
          if (n)
          {
            var a = this.elements[0];
            "number" == typeof i && i < this.elements.length && (a = this.elements[i]), this.toggleElement(a, !1)
          }
          c.attachEvents()
        },
        setTransition: function (e)
        {
          var t = this.options,
            n = t.duration,
            i = t.answerClass,
            s = e.querySelector("." + i),
            r = a("transition");
          s.style[r] = n + "ms"
        },
        generateID: function (e)
        {
          e.setAttribute("id", "ac-".concat(s)), s++
        },
        setARIA: function (e)
        {
          var t = this.options,
            n = t.questionClass,
            i = t.answerClass,
            s = e.querySelector("." + n),
            r = e.querySelector("." + i);
          s.setAttribute("role", "tab"), s.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false"), r.setAttribute("role", "tabpanel")
        },
        updateARIA: function (e, t)
        {
          var n = this.options.questionClass;
          e.querySelector("." + n).setAttribute("aria-expanded", t)
        },
        callSpecificElement: function (e)
        {
          for (var t = e.target, n = this.options, i = n.questionClass, s = n.targetClass, r = n.closeOthers, a = 0; a < this.elements.length; a++)
            if (this.elements[a].contains(t))
            {
              (t.className.match(i) || t.className.match(s)) && (e.preventDefault(), r && this.closeAllElements(a), this.toggleElement(this.elements[a]));
              break
            }
        },
        hideElement: function (e)
        {
          var t = this.options.answerClass;
          e.querySelector("." + t).style.height = 0
        },
        toggleElement: function (e, t)
        {
          var n, i = !(1 < arguments.length && void 0 !== t) || t,
            s = this.options,
            r = s.answerClass,
            a = s.aria,
            o = s.onToggle,
            l = e.querySelector("." + r),
            c = l.scrollHeight;
          e.classList.toggle("is-active"), i || (l.style.height = "auto"), 0 < parseInt(l.style.height) ? (n = !1, requestAnimationFrame(function ()
          {
            l.style.height = 0
          })) : (n = !0, requestAnimationFrame(function ()
          {
            l.style.height = c + "px"
          })), a && this.updateARIA(e, n), i && o(e, this.elements)
        },
        closeAllElements: function (e)
        {
          for (var t = this.options.aria, n = this.elements.length, i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (i != e)
            {
              var s = this.elements[i];
              s.classList.contains("is-active") && s.classList.remove("is-active"), t && this.updateARIA(s, !1), this.hideElement(s)
            }
        },
        resizeHandler: function ()
        {
          for (var e, t, n = this.options, i = n.elementClass, s = n.answerClass, r = this.container.querySelectorAll("." + i + ".is-active"), a = 0; a < r.length; a++) t = r[a].querySelector("." + s), requestAnimationFrame(function ()
          {
            t.style.height = "auto", e = t.offsetHeight, requestAnimationFrame(function ()
            {
              t.style.height = e + "px"
            })
          })
        },
        clickHandler: function (e)
        {
          this.callSpecificElement(e)
        },
        keydownHandler: function (e)
        {
          13 === e.keyCode && this.callSpecificElement(e)
        }
      };
    this.attachEvents = function ()
    {
      var e = t;
      e.clickHandler = e.clickHandler.bind(e), e.keydownHandler = e.keydownHandler.bind(e), e.resizeHandler = e.resizeHandler.bind(e), e.container.addEventListener("click", e.clickHandler), e.container.addEventListener("keydown", e.keydownHandler), i.addEventListener("resize", e.resizeHandler)
    }, this.detachEvents = function ()
    {
      var e = t;
      e.container.removeEventListener("click", e.clickHandler), e.container.removeEventListener("keydown", e.keydownHandler), i.removeEventListener("resize", e.resizeHandler)
    };
    var a = function (e)
      {
        return "string" == typeof document.documentElement.style[e] ? e : (e = n(e), e = "webkit".concat(e))
      },
      n = function (e)
      {
        return e.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + e.slice(1)
      },
      h = function (e, t)
      {
        for (var n in t) e[n] = t[n];
        return e
      };
    i.requestAnimationFrame = i.requestAnimationFrame || i.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || function (e)
    {
      i.setTimeout(e, 1e3 / 60)
    }, t.init()
  }
  var s = 0;
  "undefined" != typeof module && void 0 !== module.exports ? module.exports = u : i.Accordion = u
}(window);

</script>    

<script>
  new Accordion('.accordion-container'); 
</script>
```

I can insert in in an article and it works. But nothing happens when I try to add an anchor. I suppose it requires additional javascript.

I have found an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447803/open-a-specific-accordion-panel-with-an-external-anchor-link/50448207), but I still do not see anchors working when i run it locally, neither i can insert it into joomla article properly.

I also tried many of [these](https://freefrontend.com/css-accordions/) accordions. But only [this one](https://codepen.io/JeremyWink/pen/PoYdrLV?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=65841cbae77bb00196e4f6f62a0c45d464066e19-1595238428-0-AQ5l1jjuACZ2CSYO1ZZzV7CrgDPd9dt15JsBqDw8TK9XbbVjYPFJUxmeUQ5RV2gFOkKZ2LONu4r2aVKbdj6l3ELQj5eokjuXc8A2-qCkdVcEyUPe5M1S6O1sNyqSwSh9FF1PB3Nky3gzbBez1vcd8Utffeti0iwf_YbXjgwvFTuI5Nk_OXYnKXAVujPjVE8_iVK4wtYgglOfbHAQNP-pjEztR3c-xN9WkMM-DO0UJkk9m8KrT2h6WAIqMPrH7mMkBYaEHVloLBdIMRoVB--b1NZWYxokDzBQLK_I782lGJ4zcLOg4CvXdyLHo6ykOr4KCj5r98bH56PqBP6l5dIHFqsZ-XUx_iGUDiCVrRlx97em) has anchors. But it doesn't work, when I try to edit the text or add fields.

I would appreciate any help very much, or some links to guides, thank you!

Comment: This looks like a "requirements dump".  In other words, you have come to Stack Overflow, have shown no evidence of research or toil, and expect volunteers to perform multiple tasks for you ...for free.  This is not the goal of SO.  Please edit your question to show your best coding attempt and show us which tutorials you found to help you.  I would invite you to post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange, but your question would Needs More Focus there too.

Comment: @mickmackusa Yeah, you're right, sorry for negligence. I've edited my post.

Comment: @mickmackusa Do you have any comments to the form of the question now?

Comment: Sorry, I am fighting a deadline for work.  I don't have time to read the updated question now.  I am happy to see that you've posted on JSE though.

Comment: Partial solution was given [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28296/14420).